# Trying to delete all files in a folder exept 2 selected files in c#

Tags: c#, delete-file

I'm just trying to write a simple program that clears out my "Path" folder exept for 2 .exe files preselected. The problem is that I only succeed in deleting the first one (file1.exe).
What am I doing wrong? Forgive me if I'm using the logical operators but in this moment is like my head is about to explode...

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    var name = new FileInfo(filePath).Name;
    name = name.ToLower();
    if (name != "file1.exe" || name != "file2.exe")
    {
            File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is the premise behind the "[I have two coins in my pocket that total $0.55 and one is not a nickel](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69484.html)" riddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `||` for your condition.

```
if (name != "file1.exe" && name != "file2.exe")
```

You can also filter out the files with LINQ expression like:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path)
                        .Where(r=> !r.Equals("file1.exe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                   && !r.Equals("file2.exe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

and then you can do:

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't. make sure your file is named as same as in the string for comparison.

Comment: When you do your string comparison, make sure you ignore case.

Comment: Also... add me as another vote for using && instead of ||

Comment: Yes thank you, it was an uppercase letter that was doing the trick!

Comment: Great... I'm glad the Stack Overflow community was able to help you.  Since you're new, I'd like to remind you to close out this question by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically saying, if name is not equal to "file1.exe" OR name != "file2.exe" then delete a file path, the problem is you are using a OR logical operator so it only deletes one. Try using &&.